# Dust coating a length of road that is 1.25 miles long.

Tags: arithmetic

A length of road is 1.25 miles.
8 landowners along the road would like to split the cost of dust coating the road.
The cost of dust coating is at $53 per 100 feet.
The county will reimburse the landowners 55% of the total cost.
How much will each landowner need to pay is the cost is split equally?

Comment: What have you tried?  What is the total cost to be paid?  You need to convert 1.25 miles to feet.

Comment: @RossMillikan For me as European that is precisely the hard part of it ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen One mile is eight furlongs. One furlong is 110 fathoms, I guess you know the rest.

Comment: And in Canada, dust on the roads is free.

Comment: @DanielFischer one furlong is ten chains. So 1.25 miles is in fact 100 chains.

Comment: @Joffan I have broken my chains. Vive la revolution!

Answer (score 1):

A length of road is 1.25 miles. 8 landowners along the road would like to split the cost of dust coating the road. The cost of dust coating is at $53 per 100 feet. The county will reimburse the landowners 55% of the total cost. How much will each landowner need to pay if the cost is split equally?

First we need to determine the cost for the dust, so we need to convert the miles to feet, so we set up a proportion. $\frac{x}{1.25}=\frac{5280}{1}$. Solving for $x$, we get $6600$ ft.

Now we set up a new proportion to find out the cost, $\frac{y}{6600}=\frac{53}{100}$. Solving for $y$ we get $3,498.

Since the landowners are being reimbursed 55% of the cost, they're paying 100%-55%=45% of the cost. Thus they are paying 3498*0.45=$1574.10. Now we divide this amount by 8, and for each landowner they will pay 1574.10/8 = 196.76 dollars.